# How to download xcode 6 beta ? and How i can keep both xcode 5 and xcode 6 in the same machine?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios8, xcode6

Can anyone provide me the link to download xcode 6 beta version? And please tell me how i can keep it along with the previous version in my machine.

Thanks

Comment: You can use xcode select to switch between versions sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is what I had to do

1) Go to https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/ios/index.action

2) If you are still not **Update Program License Agreement**, don't forget to do it

3) Click on **iOS 8 beta** tab.

4) Scroll down and click **Download** XCode

Answer (score 5):

If you are an Apple Developer for iOS or Mac OS X, which is $99 a year, go to the Xcode page and scroll down to [Xcode 6](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/downloads/) .

Apple won't provide freely a beta of Xcode.Xcode 6 will be free once it reached a release version.
Though, you'll be able to find XCode on non legal downloading site [download here](http://thepiratebay.se/torrent/10283835/xCode_6_beta_%286A215l%29).

You can install multiple versions of Xcode. They will install into separate directories.

Answer (score 1):

At the apple developer center https://developer.apple.com/xcode/downloads/

and yes you can keep both versions

Answer (score 1):

always u get in the updates from https://developer.apple.com/xcode/downloads for related in the MAC and iOS

it is possible one.  we can make the two Xcode in our system, its  default set one is original and another one is `Duplicate` or `Xcode 2`

Answer (score 1):

- When you will download the Xcode_6_beta, it will be in download
  directory then keep this in different directory compared to Xcode old
  directory.
- Follow the step to download Xcode 6 beta version

1>Login in member centre

2>Select iOS Developer

3>Select **iOS 8 beta 2** (Beside **iOS 7 SDK** tab)

4>Scroll down you will get the option to download(Xcode 6 beta 2)

- **Note:- If you r not paid developer then you can't download**